# Best way of automating a mailshot process

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, ms-office

I looking at automating  a mailshot process. Currently the mail merge is done in word with data coming from SQL Server. This produces a letter, then depending on a value on the letter a number of brochures are manually added to the envelope with the letter. What I am trying to do, is automatically print the correct number of pdfs behind the letter. For example when the merge is run and the first letter has a PDFCount  (field from the query) of 3, the letter is printer and then 3 pdfs are printed before the next letter. 
Whats the best way of achieving this?

Comment: Do you still want to do the mail merge in word or are you looking to do that using PDF technology instead?

Comment: Or... are you just looking for a solution that will automatically and silently print PDFs to the printer?

Comment: I open to options. The PDfs (brochures) need to be printed behind each letter.

Comment: It might be easier to convert the pdf brochure to word, then insert that into the mailmerge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I could find to sort this, was to convert the PDF to word, and insert the brochure into the the mailmerge when needed